# Julia: How to pretty print an array?

Tags: julia

```
a= zeros(4,4)
```

Print `a` like this

```
> 4×4 Array{Float64,2}:
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

but `println(a)` prints like this

```
[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
```

How can I "print" `a` in the former way within a function? I want it fo debugging purposes.

Comment: use `display` ?

Comment: Wow didn't know about this one, thanks !

Comment: The answers here are already sufficient, but in case you would like to show the expression being printed, I've written a couple handy macros to do just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77020508

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Use `display(x)`.**

Let me comment here on what is going on here. A key difference is between `show(io, x)` and `show(io, mime, x)`, as you can see in the docs:

> help?> show(stdout, a)
> show([io::IO = stdout], x)
>
> Write a text representation of a value x to the output stream io. New types T
> should overload show(io::IO, x::T). The representation used by show generally
> includes Julia-specific formatting and type information, and should be
> parseable Julia code when possible.
>
> repr returns the output of show as a string.
>
> To customize human-readable text output for objects of type T, define
> show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", ::T) instead. Checking the :compact IOContext
> property of io in such methods is recommended, since some containers show their
> elements by calling this method with :compact => true.

So:

- `show` without MIME writes a text representation of an object,
- `show` with MIME tries to produce a human-readable format.

Now `print(io, x)` fallsback to `show(io, x)` as you can see here:

```
function print(io::IO, x)
    lock(io)
    try
        show(io, x)
    finally
        unlock(io)
    end
    return nothing
end
```

and `display` by default in REPL falls back to `show(io, mime, a)`:

```
function display(d::REPLDisplay, mime::MIME"text/plain", x)
    io = outstream(d.repl)
    get(io, :color, false) && write(io, answer_color(d.repl))
    if isdefined(d.repl, :options) && isdefined(d.repl.options, :iocontext)
        # this can override the :limit property set initially
        io = foldl(IOContext, d.repl.options.iocontext,
                   init=IOContext(io, :limit => true, :module => Main))
    end
    show(io, mime, x)
    println(io)
    nothing
end
```

(in both cases I have copied definitions from the Base, that you end up getting using default `print(a)` and `display(a)` operations - skipping methods that are called in the process)

You can find more information about it [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-custom-pretty-printing-1) in the Julia manual.

So in your case - as Jun Tian suggested you can use `display`. Also just to show that this all falls back to `show`:

```
julia> a = zeros(4,4);

julia> show(stdout, a)
[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
julia> show(stdout, "text/plain", a)
4×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes you want to save that line showing the size and type. Hence, another option worth noting is `DelimitedFiles`:

```
julia> a= zeros(4,4);

julia> using DelimitedFiles; writedlm(stdout, a)
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Indeed sometimes it is useful, but for large arrays (especially of floats) it is problematic as it does not use compact representation and does not respect horizontal and vertical size of the terminal. E.g. compare the results of `display` and `writedlm` for `rand(100,100)`.

Comment: Oh, I like this - it works even for very long arrays.