# Julia: how to get an error message and stacktrace as string?

Tags: julia

I am trying to get an error message of a caught exception for use in a warning.

For example, while following

```
julia> a = 3+b
ERROR: UndefVarError: b not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[1]:1
```

says that the problem is that `b` is not defined, the following method of handling exception has much less helpful message:

```
julia> try
           a = 3+b
       catch e
           @warn "Bad thing happend: $e"
       end
┌ Warning: Bad thing happend: UndefVarError(:b)
└ @ Main REPL[2]:4
```

How do I get the error message and stacktrace from the exception as String?

Answer (score 2):

While a bit wordy, the answer seems to be by using the `Base.showerror(io::IO, err::MyException)` function defined for builtin exceptions:

```
julia> try
           a = 3+b
       catch e
           io = IOBuffer();
           showerror(io, e)
           error_msg = String(take!(io))
           @warn "Trouble doing things:\n$(error_msg)"
       end
┌ Warning: Trouble doing things:
│ UndefVarError: b not defined
└ @ Main REPL[3]:7
```

To also get the stacktrace:

1. use `stacktrace(catch_backtrace())` to get the stacktrace vector from the place exception was thrown (see [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/stacktraces/#Error-handling))
2. use `show(io, mime, x)` to format the vector nicely (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868864/julia-how-to-pretty-print-an-array) SO answer)

Combining the two with the `sprint` that handles the IOBuffer for us, we get to:

```
julia> try
           a = 3+b
       catch e
           error_msg = sprint(showerror, e)
           st = sprint((io,v) -> show(io, "text/plain", v), stacktrace(catch_backtrace()))
           @warn "Trouble doing things:\n$(error_msg)\n$(st)"
       end
┌ Warning: Trouble doing things:
│ UndefVarError: b not defined
│ 13-element Vector{Base.StackTraces.StackFrame}:
│  top-level scope at REPL[4]:2
│  eval at boot.jl:373 [inlined]
│  ...
└ @ Main REPL[4]:6
```

Comment: You can use [`sprint`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.sprint): `sprint(showerror, e)` to get the string.

Comment: That's an awesome method, thanks for that!