# Is there a `dbg!`-like macro for Julia?

Tags: debugging, formatting, julia, output

Rust has the incredibly convenient `dbg!` macro:

```rust
fn main() {
  dbg!(1 + 2);
}
```

The above code outputs `[src/main.rs:2] 1 + 2 = 3`.

Is there anything similar for Julia?

Or perhaps there's something else that serves my use case? I'd like to be able to output each one of my results, but removing the semicolon only displays the result for the last thing without a semicolon (instead of all things like MATLAB).

Comment: Maybe you want `@show 1+2`?

Comment: And if you want the file and line information, `@__FILE__()` and `@__LINE__()` are your friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of macros built-in which do this:

```
julia> let x = 7
         @show x^2
         @info "cube of $x" x^3
         @warn "minus" -x maxlog=3
       end
x ^ 2 = 49
┌ Info: cube of 7
└   x ^ 3 = 343
┌ Warning: minus
│   -x = -7
└ @ Main REPL[42]:4
```

While the first just prints to stdout (see e.g. `@macroexpand @show x`), macros `@info` and `@warn` use the Logging module, which has various more complex features, including suppressing some printout. `@warn` and `@error` print details of the call site, which (as @BallpointBen
mentions) can also be had directly from special macros `@__MODULE__`, `@__FILE__` and `@__LINE__`.

Answer (score 0):

@mcabbott answered the question as asked (so I marked his answer as accepted), but I just wanted to add a couple snippets showcasing some relevant and handy macros I came up with:

EDIT: I've updated these macros in accordance with @mcabbott's suggestions in the comments below this answer.

```
# Compact show
macro showc(exs...)
    blk = Expr(:block)
    for ex in exs
        push!(blk.args, :(println($(sprint(Base.show_unquoted,ex)*" = "),
        repr(begin local value = $(esc(ex)) end, context = :compact=>true) * "\n")))
    end
    isempty(exs) || push!(blk.args, :value)
    return blk
end

# Pretty show
macro showp(exs...)
    blk = Expr(:block)
    for ex in exs
        push!(blk.args, :(println($(sprint(Base.show_unquoted,ex)*" = "),
        repr(MIME("text/plain"), begin local value = $(esc(ex)) end, context = :limit=>true) * "\n")))
    end
    isempty(exs) || push!(blk.args, :value)
    return blk
end
```

Given the following variables:

```
PY1Y2 = [0.018 0.035 0.031 0.008 0.018;
         0.002 0.112 0.064 0.032 0.069;
         0.001 0.066 0.094 0.032 0.084;
         0.001 0.018 0.019 0.010 0.051;
         0.001 0.029 0.032 0.043 0.130];

d = PY1Y2[:, 1] ./ sum(PY1Y2[:, 1]);
```

`@showp d;` will display:

```
d = 5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.7826086956521738
 0.08695652173913043
 0.043478260869565216
 0.043478260869565216
 0.043478260869565216
```

`@showc d;` will display:

```
d = [0.782609, 0.0869565, 0.0434783, 0.0434783, 0.0434783]
```

compared to the built-in `@show d;`:

```
d = [0.7826086956521738, 0.08695652173913043, 0.043478260869565216, 0.043478260869565216, 0.043478260869565216]
```

Comment: Note that these won't work inside a function, as `eval` works in global scope. It also calls the enclosed code twice. `@macroexpand @show f(x)` avoids both of these problems; you could modify code from `@less @show f(x)` to change the printing, adding a keyword like `repr(2pi; context = :compact => true)`. (Here `repr` prints e.g. strings with quotes, as in `let s = "hi"; @show s; nothing end`.)

Comment: @mcabbott I've updated the answer. Does my solution look good to you now?

Comment: These look good to me. You may wish to consider `context = :limit=>true` for the second, e.g. try `@showp 1 2 rand(100)'` and notice that it prints all numbers, while the REPL by default truncates to one screen-width.